# Draw multiple car when click Java

Tags: java, jframe, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I have written a program to draw 1 car when I click the mouse button, now I want to draw 1 more car when I click a second time on the mouse button.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
```

public class CarMove extends JComponent

{

```
private volatile boolean drawCar = false;
private volatile boolean drawCar1 = false;

private int lastX = 0;
private int clickCount = 0;

{
    FrameMouseListener listener = new FrameMouseListener();
    super.addMouseListener(listener);
}

public CarMove() 
{
    Thread animationThread = new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            while (true) 
            {
                repaint();
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(10);

                } catch (Exception ex) {}
            }
        }
    });

    animationThread.start();
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{

     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

     if (drawCar) 
     {
         int x = 1;
         int carSpeed = 1;
         int w = getWidth(); 
         x = lastX + carSpeed;
        //create the car from draw class
         Car car1 = new Car(x,320);
         car1.draw(g2);   
         lastX = x; 
     }   
     if (drawCar1) 
     {
         int x = 1;
         int carSpeed = 1;
         int w = getWidth(); 
         x = lastX + carSpeed;
        //create the car from draw class
         Car car2 = new Car(x,320);
         car2.draw(g2);   
         lastX = x; 
     }   
}
public class FrameMouseListener implements MouseListener
{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) 
    {
        if (clickCount == 1)
        {
            drawCar = true;
            repaint();  
        }
        if (clickCount == 2)
        {
            drawCar1 = true;
            repaint();
        }

    }
```

I try to create the boolean drawcar 2 times but It did not work please help me.

Comment: Please past complete code (this does not compile) or use an int to decide how many car you should draw, then loop and draw them number you need.

Comment: I need to draw 20 cars when every time I click on the mouse and its will spawn on the screen and then run to the left.  I will post complete code.

Comment: Try with a for loop, (i=0;i<20;i++) and draw them all..., be sure to format the code you past... I will not do it again...

Comment: If I write a loop there, how can the compiler know I click on the first click then second click.

Comment: add an int clickCounter, and in the listener do clickCounter=clickCounter+1; or (same code but shorter) clickCounter++; Then check the clickCounter and decide how many cars to draw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need to know how many times the user clicked the mouseButton.

```
@Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m) {
        int clickCount = m.getClickCount();

        //change your code to do draw the cars based on clicks
    }
```

**Edit:**

when you call repaint method always the first line must be:

```
super.repaint();
```

To draw multiple cars you have to use a loop when you call the **paint(Graphics g)** like:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.repaint();

   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

   for(int car=0; car<totalClicks; car++){

    //Here add your code to draw the cars
    if(car==1){
       //do this
    }else if(car==2){
       //do that
    }else if(car== 3){
       //do more
    }else if(car==4){
       //hard job 
    }//etc

 }
```

Comment: I just edit my code like u said but the second car still not appear